# Using trace on a hidden function to edit source code in R

Tags: r, debugging, trace

For a package I am using, I would like to fix part of the code. I have downloaded the "package source" [from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html) and have narrowed down where the problem is. I would like to edit the problem function in RStudio. I've tried using `trace`, but I am unable to call the desired function. The function I want to call is a helper function (not in the documentation) to the main function (which is in the documentation). Is there a way to edit the functions not in the documentation and used in the implementation?

If it helps, the package I am using is called [`RecordLinkage`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html). I would like to change the function `.toFF` which is called by `RLBigDataDedup` and is in the file `RLBigData-classes.r`.
[image]
Now that I've established the problem by looking at the source code, I now want to edit it in RStudio so that I can run it when using the package... The best I can do is looking at `RLBigDataDedup` in RStudio, but I can't find the `.toFF` that is used within it.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not working because the hidden function `.toFF` is not known in the global env because it is hidden. If you want to edit/debug hidden function you have to specify the `where` argument in `trace()` with the corresponding function. In your case it would be `RLBigDataLinkage`.

Regarding to the [`docs`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trace.html) of `trace`, it is stated:

> For “hidden” functions such as S3 methods in a namespace, where = *
>   typically needs to be specified as well

So for your answer this will work:

```
trace(".toFF", edit=T, where = RLBigDataLinkage)
```

Comment: I think it might need to be trace(".toFF", edit=T, where=asNamespace(RLBigDataLinkage))

Answer (score -1):

try `debug(.toFF)` or `debug(function_to_calls_.toFF)` This will open the debug tool when the function is called.

Comment: Both debug(.toFF) and trace(.toFF) throw an error: object '.toFF' not found... Similarly for debug(function_to_calls_.toFF).